# MS Access need to hide fields based on linked combo box

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have one table, let's call it "leagues".  Is this table, the fields are simply the league name, and then about 15 other yes/no fields.

I then have a second table and related form.  Lets call that "Games".  The idea is that when the user selects any given league (which is a linked field to the first table), then I want only certain fields to show up based on the yes/no criteria.

I've found two other posts that offer some ideas, but I don't quite see my exact situation.
[Hide Controls in MS Access Based on Value Field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25510206/hide-controls-in-ms-access-based-on-value-field)
and
[Ms Access Hide and Show Fields based on combo box choice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29893693/ms-access-hide-and-show-fields-based-on-combo-box-choice)

In addition, All those other fields that may or may not be visible are all linked fields to a third table called "members".  I want to ensure that when a certain member is selected in any given field, they cannot be selected in any other field for the current record.  I can use validation rules on each control, but I feel there is an easier way.

Please, steer me in the right direction, and if you can offer sample code, that would help.

Comment: Can you create a concatenated list of the fields based on the Yes/No in the first form and use that to build a query to populate the second form? Seems easier to simply query the desired fields for the second form than hide unwanted ones.

Comment: Anything is possible.  I am simply looking for the easiest, and most user friendly way to accomplish this.

Comment: I should also add that the user should be able to add/delete/edit the leagues, and members at any time.  So as long at the concatenate list is updated in real time that might work.